# Kitematic docker config yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, kitematic

I spawned one docker container using kitematic.

I was following another tutorial related to a specific deployment need and want access to the yml file which contains the settings.

Can anybody help me know where does Kitematic store yml dockerfile  corresponding to a docker container?

Comment: If you think the answer provided below has helped you, you could mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's some confusion here. Just to be sure, a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) is not a [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) file, they are two different things.

A `Dockerfile` defines an image while a `docker-compose.yml` file defines a container, [about images and containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_two/).

What Kitematic does is to download an image and let you modify from UI the `ENV` variables defined in the `Dockerfile`, check the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env).

If you want to check the `Dockerfile` of an image from the Kitematic UI:

- Go to the main page
- click on the button with the `...` symbol
- click on `VIEW ON DOCKER HUB`
- from that page check the latest Dockerfile.

Kitematic has a caching\config folder in (Windows):

```
C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\Kitematic
```

But they are just binary files used for caching downloaded images, there's no configuration there (at least in clear text) and for sure no `docker-compose.yml` files.